# Perform zoning on irregular points by value (nutrient distribution)

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, interpolation

I would like to perform a zoning (nutrient distribution) of a agricultural land. I got the bounding and inside them irregular probe points with different values (phosphorus content - P).
Now I would like to perform a zoning with 4 or 5 classes as result.

What I did: I was interpolating the points using v.surf.rst and styled with discrete values. You can see the result in the screenshot below.

But the result should more look like this: https://www.dlg.org/de/landwirtschaft/themen/pflanzenbau/pflanzenernaehrung/dlg-merkblatt-407-teilflaechenspezifische-bodenprobennahme-und-duengung#&gid=lightbox-group-84095&pid=0

What is the method to get a zoning like that?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some datasets.